# How to find the amount of duplicates in a list in C# ASP.NET Core Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

If you have the following list:

```
new List<int> { 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7 }
```

how can you know that the list contains 1 twice, 5 once, 6 once and 7 three times with Linq?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to group the array by the values and count each group and filter out groups that have a count > 1.

```
    var values = new List<int> { 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7 };
    var duplicatedValues = from v in values
                           group v by v into valuesGrouped
                           where valuesGrouped.Count() > 1
                           select valuesGrouped.Key;
    var duplicatedCount = duplicatedValues.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());
```

This should return dictionary, with number as key and count as value.

Answer (score 0):

For this you use the overload of [GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-2)))).

The idea is that you  make groups of integers that have the same value. With parameter resultSelector you define what you want to do with this *same value* and with the elements in the group.

Your source is very simple: just a sequence of integers. This might make your query a bit strange:

```
IEnumerable<int> mySource = ...

// make groups of integers that have the same value:
var duplicateCount = mySource.GroupBy(i => i,  // i becomes the key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every key, and all elements that have this key
    // make one new object:
    (key, elementsThatHaveThisKey) => new
    {
        IntegerValue = key,
        NumberOfElementsThatHaveThisIntegerValue = elementsThatHaveThisKey.Count(),
    });
```

If your source would be objects of some class, than the query would look less weird:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDay {get; set;}
}
```

How many people are born on the same date?

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ...

// make groups of Persons that have the same BirthDay
var countSameBirthDay = person.GroupBy(person => person.BirthDay,
   // key is birtday, all elements in the group will have the same value for
   // property BirthDay

    // parameter resultSelector: from every found BirthDay,
    // with all Persons that have this value for BirthDay,
    // make one new object:
    (birthDay, personsBornOnThisDate) => new
    {
        BirthDay = birthDay,
        NumberOfPersonsBornOnBirthDay = personsBornOnThisDate.Count(),
    });
```